# Time for read queries jumped unexpectedly in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, cron, amazon-rds, database-deadlocks

I am facing an issue while reading data from database(PostgreSQL version = 11.6). The read queries were working fine until yesterday. But now it's taking way too long to open a specific table rest all other tables are working fine. I am using TablePlus as a client to connect to RDS.
Running a simple select query is taking a lot of time

```
SELECT * FROM "public"."scraped_accounts" ORDER BY "id" LIMIT ? OFFSET ?;
```

[CPU USAGE GRAPH  FOR THE ABOVE QUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kucpz.jpg)

Table Specifications

- There are just 5,737 records in the table.
- It is hosted on db.m4.large instance on AWS.
- There are no specific indexes except the primary key index on column id and uses BTREE Algorithm

The structure of the table is as given below

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."scraped_accounts" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('scraped_accounts_id_seq'::regclass),
    "screen_name" text NOT NULL,
    "name" text NOT NULL,
    "url" text,
    "description" text,
    "location" text,
    "score" numeric NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL,
    "scraped_at" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "img" text,
    "cover_img" text,
    "interested" _text NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::text[],
    "checked" bool DEFAULT false,
    "ignore" bool DEFAULT false,
    "tag" text,
    "sector" text,
    "last" text,
    "total" text,
    "meta_title" text,
    "meta_description" text,
    "meta_keywords" text,
    "name" text,
    "url" text,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

I have tried:

1. Rebooting the instance of Database
2. Exporting this specific table and importing into another instance of the database.
3. Tried searching for locks

But still the same issue persists.

Suspected issues can be related to:

1. Emojis which are present in the data. There might be issue because of their encoding format
2. We are running multiple cron jobs at the backend which do INSERT and UPDATE queries simultaneously on this table.

Can above mentioned reasons cause this issue?

[CLOUD WATCH GRAPHS FOR PAST ONE WEEK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIYpw.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There could be many factors. The first thing to recommend is not to use text but more specific types with size constrained like varchar(100) for name (is just an example) Make a better study of the data you want to store,you have many unlimited text fields which might be slowing it down depending on the RDS instance you have and the amount of data. Also consider indexes and projections in your queries to speed them up

Comment: it would help if you could show us the query you are using, and the definition of any other indexes on the table.

Comment: @ChrisCurvey I have added some more information regarding the issue. Please have a look.

Comment: That's a pretty simple query, and 5K rows is a very small table.

Is there a chance that one of your "text" fields has gotten huge, and it is just taking a long time to send the results over the network from AWS to your client machine?  (You already said that you had not found any locking issues.)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions -

1. If the `Interested` column which contains an array of `text` values becomes too big, it will cause your queries to slow down.
2. Recheck for deadlocks ->  https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/02/15/when-postgresql-blocks/
3. I'm not sure if huge text values could cause your queries to slow down but might be worth checking anyway. Try running this ->

`SELECT id, description, LENGTH(description) FROM scraped_accounts WHERE description IS NOT NULL ORDER BY LENGTH DESC`

This should give you an idea about the size of your text values.